# implementing custom css with primefaces 3.1

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working with Primefaces 3.1 and I am trying to implement custom css for button.

I have my page defined like following:

```
<h:head>
<title>Primefaces 3.1</title>
<f:facet name="last">             
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8" /> 
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>                           
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/Styles/stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/Styles/pfOverride.css" type="text/css" />
    </f:facet> 
</h:head>
```

CommandButton looks like this:

```
<p:commandButton id="button1" styleClass="custButton"....
```

pfOverride.css has following:

```
.ui-button {
    background-color: #b2f5g3;
    border-color: black;    
}

.ui-button-text {
    background-color: #b2f5g3;
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text {
    font-size: 9pt; 
    color: black;
}
```

And custButton also has different values set,

My problem is pfoverride.css is working but stylesheet is not. Can somebody tell me what I am missing or doing wrong, I tried putting `!important` also but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you add the closing bracket to the `.ui-button-text` and use a correct hexadecimal value (`g` is not a hex digit):

```css
.ui-button-text {
    background-color: #b2f5f3;
}
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text {
    font-size: 9pt; 
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo but I said already pfOverride.css is working fine but my stylesheet class .custButton inside styleclass.css is not. How do I load stylesheet so that I can only use stylesheet. Looks like its ignoring my stylesheet.

Comment: I tried the code in my IDE and it works fine. The only difference is that I included the styles direclty on the page and not from a separate file.

Comment: I was looking not to use the .ui-button-text class or .ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text class like above but only use the custom class like .custCutton class from stylesheet and change the look n feel of the P:commandButton, Is it possible?